# implement operator ‘[]’ for class ‘CMatrix’

Tags: overloading, operator-keyword

```
 #include<iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class Array {  
   private:

       int * data;
       int size;
       int isValidIndex();
   public:   
        Array ( )
       {  
          data = 0;   
          size = 0;   
       }   
       Array ( int );   
       Array (const Array &);
       Array & operator = ( const Array & );
       int & operator [] ( int );
       void reSize(int);
       ~Array();
 };


class CMatrix
          {
 private:   
    int * * data;    
    int row;    
    int col;    
    //isValidBounds( int , int );    
 public:    
    CMatrix ( )    
    {    
       data = 0;    
       row = col = 0;    
     }
    CMatrix ( int r, int c );    
    CMatrix ( const CMatrix & );    
    CMatrix & operator = ( const CMatrix & );    

    //many other functions

     };
```

//Do you feel suitable to implement operator ‘[]’ for class ‘CMatrix’ such that we should be able to manipulate them as follows, If yes then give the definition of operator ‘[]’ for ‘CMatrix’, otherwise given reason (solid/pinpoint) for not implementing this operator.

```
    main()            
    {
    CMatrix m(3,4); //3 by 4 matrix where ist row/col index is 0    
    m[1][2] = 67;    
    cout << m[1][2]; //should display 67        
    }
```

Comment: I'm unable to make out what your query is?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal the code given in the main fucntion is giving error, Answer why it show error, and what will be the solution..Do you feel suitable to implement operator ‘[]’ for class ‘CMatrix’ such that we should be able to manipulate them as follows, If yes then give the definition of operator ‘[]’ for ‘CMatrix’, otherwise given reason (solid/pinpoint) for not implementing this operator.. 
This is question i got in exam, and i want to solve and get ans